# jQuery - JSON to populate dropdown list

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list from a jQuery call that requires JSON. I found on the web the following code which is my starting point (Java and Spring 3), but I accept other/better approaches:

The JSP (only relevant code shown):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#parkName').change(
                function(){
                    alert($(this).val());
                    $.getJSON('${findUnitsURL}', {
                        parkName : $(this).val(),
                        ajax : 'true'
                    }, function(data) {
                        var html = '<option value="">City</option>';
                        var len = data.length;
                        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            html += '<option value="' + data[i].name + '">'
                                + data[i].name + '</option>';
                        }
                        html += '</option>';

                        $('#parkUnitTitleAersa').html(html);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>


<div id="content">

                <form:form method="post" action="mainForm" commandName="mainForm">

                    <form:select id="parkName" path="parkName">
                        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                        <form:options items="${parkList}" />
                    </form:select>

                    <form:select id="parkUnitTitleAersa" path="parkUnitTitleAersa">
                        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                        <form:options items="${parkUnitList}" />
                    </form:select>

                    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
                    </form:form>

            </div>
```

Java controller who has the requested method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "units", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> unitsForPark(@RequestParam(value = "parkName", required = true) String parkName) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("AA01");
        l.add("AA02");
        l.add("LA03");
        l.add("SG04");

        return l;
    }
```

When I select a value in "parkName" dropdown the other is not populated. Using firebug I get this error:

```
[10:46:39.881] GET http://localhost:8084/SpringBlog/units?parkName=LA&ajax=true [HTTP/1.1 406 No Aceptable 62ms]
```

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: can you show the actual request done to the server by the script? and if you use "by hand" the url to retrieve the data, do you receive what you expect?

Comment: [`406`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) points to a Spring problem in that Spring doesn't know how to create a `JSON` view of the data, since `$.getJSON` is setting the header `Accept: application/json`. You should look at Spring's [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html) and [MappingJacksonJsonView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: What do you mean by "by hand"? Writing it directly into the browser? I've tried that but it retrieves an error (I'm probably not doing it properly....) Could you show me an example, please?

Comment: @andyb: In fact, I haven't done any JSON configuration, though I saw it was necessary adding some Jackson dependencies. However I don't know where to add them...

Comment: I meant to check the answer of the server by using a "generic client", even the browser (copying the URL in the address bar) should  have worked someway (the difference will be in the accept-.. headers, allowing you to check the server answer in that case, at least in theory). But Hauri gave you already a better insight of the problem.

Comment: Assuming you have [`<mvc:annotation-driven/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) in your Spring configuration already? If so then it might just be that Jackson is not on the classpath when running Spring. Just add it to you classpath or as a dependency if using Maven, Ivy, Gradle etc...

Comment: @ShinTakezu: The browser answer to the URL is similar to this (translated by me from my Spanish version Firfox browser): "The identified resource for this requirement is only able to generate responses with not acceptable attributes regardind 'accept' headers of the requirement".

Comment: @andyb: Thanks, I'm on it right now. Does it require much configuration? I'm not using Maven nor any other similar, so I guess I only need to add it to web.xml....right?

Comment: Hey, now it works!! Thank you!! I just added the Jackson .jars to my project and works perfectly.

Comment: With whatever you are using to add dependencies (like Spring) to your project or web app, just add the Jackson libraries in the same way. The `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` should be added to your web application's `context` XML file.

Comment: Glad you got it all working! Summarised my comments as an answer for future reference :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`406`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) points to a Spring problem in that Spring doesn't know how to create a JSON view of the data, since [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is setting the header `Accept: application/json`. You should look at Spring's [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html) and [MappingJacksonJsonView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html)

Assuming you have [`<mvc:annotation-driven/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) in your Spring web application's context configuration already? If so then it might just be that Jackson is not on the classpath when running Spring. Just add it to you classpath manually or as a dependency if using Maven, Ivy, Gradle (or other dependency management / build tool).