# how to iterate over a list of list of objects in JSP + Spring MVC and JSTL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a list of list of objects and i am putting this nested list inside `ModelandView` object but I am not able to acccess the list on the JSP page.

```
<c:forEach items="${product.productCategoryDetails}" var="productCategoryDetails" varStatus="status">
    <tr id="category_row">
        <td><form:label path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category">Category</form:label></td>
        <td>
            <form:select cssStyle="width:134px" path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].category.id" cssClass="category">
                <form:options items="${categories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>

        <td><form:label path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].subcategory">SubCategory</form:label></td>
        <td>
            <form:select cssStyle="width:134px" path="productCategoryDetails[${status.index}].subcategory.id" cssClass="subcategory">
                <form:options items="${subCategories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Code is working perfectly for categories but it is breaking for subcategories.

`modelandview.put("subCategories", subCategories);` here, `subCategories` is a list of list of `SubCategory` objects.

Also, `ProductCategoryDetail` object has `Category` and `SubCategory` fields.

Comment: What's _breaking_? Your rendered HTML has a select with no options?

Comment: yes...for 2nd select...there is no options shown in html..

Comment: you can't use a list of lists within form:options trying to access id and name attribute because a list does not have these attributes

Comment: is there any way out of it...can i use Map<String,List<SubCategory> ??

Comment: @abhijeet see answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117557/how-to-iterate-an-arraylist-inside-a-hashmap-using-jstl

Comment: @apurv ... basically i have a set of set of 2 drop downs on a jsp page  like following...value list of options of 2nd drop down depends on the value chosen in first dropdown...so here the main problem is that i need to find a key first and then i can find list of options for second drop down but putting key into the map

Comment: So something like on click of category you want to update subcategories drop down? If yes then probably you are complicating your design. May be fetch a list of Category and a Map of subCategories and use javascript/jquery to update. requirement seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296107/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-reload-a-formselect-with-values-depending-of-the.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For subcategory in `form:select` use code below:

```
item="{productCategoryDetails.[status.index].subCategories]}"
```